# Crash while fetching NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsuserdefaults

The following code is crashing for me

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"2453"];
```

I checked and found that there is no key with name 2453 in NSUserDefaults. I am running the application for first time so this key will not be there but will be added later point in time. How to ignore this crash.

Comment: Well what's the crash log look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"2453"];
 //                                                      ^^    ^
```

The "key" in `-dictionaryForKey:` [must be an NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/dictionaryForKey%3a). It cannot be an `int`. So although the key you supplied consists only of numbers, you still have to pass in a string using `@"..."`. The fact that the key is absent is irrelevant to the crash.

Comment: My mistake in writing that here... But in code I am passing NSString only.

Comment: @Abhinav: If it's the case then it won't crash, just return `nil`. Please show the crash log.

Comment: I got it... I was getting that string from server and it was setting it as nil. So it was crashing.

Answer (score 2):

If this line

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"2453"];
```

is the line that is crashing, you might try this instead

```
NSDictionary *dict = nil;
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"2453"] != nil)
    dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"2453"];

if (dict) {
    ...
}
```

My hunch is that in this case `dictionaryForKey` is calling `objectForKey` behind the scenes and blindly trying to cast `nil` to `NSDictionary` for you, which would, I think, cause a crash. But by checking yourself first if there is any kind of object for that key, you can avoid the crash. Give it whirl and report back! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"2453"]) {
    // this line will only be reached if there is something for @"2453"
}
```